# Best practice to make root environmental variables visible to Apache under supervisord?

Tags: php, docker, apache2, amazon-elb

I have some key environmental variables set for the root user. ( I can't change this as it's done by the virtual hosting environment, docker in this case ).

However, I need Apache2/PHP to be able to see some of these variables. Apache2 is running via Supervisord, under it's own user.
Is there is way for Apache2/PHP to see these variables, currently it's missing most of them.

Any help welcome

Mike

Comment: Have you tried launching docker with this ENV? `docker run -e VAR1=$VAR1 ...`